# What is the Ruby way to pass different parameter to method, based on expression evaluation?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to achieve the following in **one line**? :

```
if foo 
  some_method this_var, other_var1, other_var2
else
  some_method that_var, other_var1, other_var2
end
```

Comment: This seems to be correct whats the problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
some_method((foo ? this_var : that_var), other_var1, other_var2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dan showed you how to do it in one line, but IMHO reducing line count at all costs is not great for readability. I'd do the following, which is shorter than what you have now and IMHO more readable than the one-liner:

```
var = foo ? this_var : that_var
some_method(var, other_var1, other_var2)
```

Comment: Great tip. It also forces you to put the logic into the controller rather than the view (in Ruby on Rails).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of the conditional operator. It is necessary in C, because in C, `if` is a statement, not an expression, whereas the conditional operator is an expression. In Ruby, however, *everything* is an expression, so, naturally, `if` is an expression, too:

```
some_method(if foo then this_var else that_var end, other_var1, other_var2)
```

However, as Michael Kohl points out, names can help clarify the intent of code, so maybe it is better to give a name to the argument:

```
meaningful_name = if foo then this_var else that_var end
some_method(meaningful_name, other_var1, other_var2)
```